# Factor $x^2+10x+21$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring

How can we factor $x^2+10x+21$? I'm a bit confused. Is the answer $(x+7)(x+3)$? I know that $7+3=10$ and $7\times 3=21$.

How can we factor $x^2+5x-24$? How about $x^2-x-20$? Why do people say $abc$ or $eb+ec$? I don't get it!

Comment: Do you have a sign error in the first problem as it is stated? Regards

Comment: My guess is that $-x^2+10x+21$ is a typo, perhaps for $-(x^2+10x+21)$.

Comment: YEAH SORRY!!!!!!!

Comment: Either a negative sign, or maybe just a hyphen?

Comment: it's x squared plus ten times x plus twenty one = x^2 + 10x + 21

Comment: You keep using hyphens to point to your equation. But that makes it impossible to distinguish from a negative sign. Also, 7+4 does not equal 10.

Comment: I keep writing the wrong numbers. grr I'll change it now

Comment: Note $7\times 3=21$ and $7+3=10$.

Answer (score 7):

Let me answer your question generally, since all three quadratics have the same form.

Suppose that you wish to factorize $x^2+px+q$. If you can find $a,b$ such that $a+b=p$ and $ab=q$, then we have $$\begin{align}x^2+px+q &= x^2+(a+b)x+ab\\ &= x^2+ax+bx+ab\\ &= (x^2+ax)+(bx+ab)\\ &= (x+a)x+(x+a)b\\ &= (x+a)(x+b).\end{align}$$

For example, consider your third quadratic, $x^2-x-20=x^2+(-1)x+(-20)$. Putting $a=4$ and $b=-5$, we have $a+b=-1=p$ and $ab=-20=q$, so we have $$x^2-x-20=(x+4)(x+-5)=(x+4)(x-5),$$ as you can (and should) check. If we're being careful, we'll actually go through the steps, so $$\begin{align}x^2-x-20 &= x^2+(4-5)x-20\\ &= x^2+4x-5x-20\\ &= (x^2+4x)+(-5x-20)\\ &= (x+4)x+(x+4)(-5)\\ &= (x+4)(x-5).\end{align}$$

---

Sometimes, though, finding such $a,b$ is an exercise in futility--we can always go by trial and error among integer factors of $q$, but sometimes that won't work. In such a situation, we can use a method called *completing the square*. We can finagle things as follows, using the fact that $(y+z)(y-z)=y^2-z^2$ for all complex $y,z$: $$\begin{align}x^2+px+q &= (x+p)x+q\\ &= \left(x+\frac{p}2+\frac{p}2\right)\left(x+\frac{p}2-\frac{p}2\right)+q\\ &= \left(x+\frac{p}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{p}2\right)^2+q\\ &= \left(x+\frac{p}2\right)^2-\frac{p^2}4+q\\ &= \left(x+\frac{p}2\right)^2-\frac{p^2-4q}4\\ &= \left(x+\frac{p}2\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{\frac{p^2-4q}4}\right)^2\\ &= \left(x+\frac{p}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2\right)^2\\ &= \left(\left(x+\frac{p}2\right)+\frac{\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2\right)\left(\left(x+\frac{p}2\right)-\frac{\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2\right)\\ &= \left(x+\frac{p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2\right)\left(x+\frac{p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2\right).\end{align}$$

We can also use the quadratic formula (which is just a shortcut to completion of the square, really), together with the fact that $x_0$ is a root of the quadratic if and only if $x-x_0$ is a factor. The quadratic formula for $x^2+px+q$ gives us the roots $$\frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2,$$ so the factors are $$x+\frac{p\mp\sqrt{p^2-4q}}2,$$ as we saw above.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming first problem written incorrectly.

$$(x+3)(x+7)$$

$$(x-3)(x+8)$$

$$(x+4)(x-5)$$

Comment: sorry it\s not a negative it's a plus x^2

Comment: @DonAntonio: It turns out is not clear what he is writing and he commented back. Is it a negative of the entire quantity or a dash. It is easy to fix. Regards

Comment: @amWhy: these are tough because the problem is a moving target. It changed like three times during people answering it!

Comment: Oh, I completely agree about the challenge of "moving targets", especially when there's **no** marker, like "Edit:..." or "Added:..." explicitly written by the OP after changing a question!!

Answer (score 0):

1.$$x^2 + 10x + 21=(x^2+7x)+(3x+21)=x(x+7)+3(x+7)=(x+3)(x+7)$$
2.$$x^2 + 5x - 24=x^2+5x-15-9=(x^2-3^2)+(5x-15)=$$
$$=(x+3)(x-3)+5(x-3)=(x-3)(x+8)$$

3.$$x^2-x-20=(x^2-5x)+(4x-20)=x(x-5)+4(x-5)=(x-5)(x+4)$$

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of looking at this kind of problem. One is to see that:$$(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$$

and identify $a$ and $b$ from the coefficients by examination. This generalises so that, for example:$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)=x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(bc+ac+ab)x+abc$$ - so the coefficients appear as elementary symmetric functions, and this works in higher degrees too. In fact we normally work with $p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ because if we want to solve $p(x)=0$ and we postulate $p(a)=0$ we find that $0=p(x)=p(x)-p(a)=(x-a)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of lower degree. It turns out to be easier to work with the roots of an equation, rather than their negatives, and we are then working with elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots. So we would conventionally write:$$(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$$

Another, more general , way of proceeding is to note that if we have $y^2=a$ then we can write $y=\pm \sqrt a$. So we rewrite $$x^2+px+q=0$$ as $$x^2+px+\frac{p^2}4=\frac{p^2}4-q$$ which is $$\left(x+\frac p2\right)^2=\frac{p^2}4-q$$ which is of the requisite form.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to factorise a quadratic expression, such as the Quadratic identities, where:

1. $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$
2. $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$
3. $a^2+b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$,

And there is another way to factorise a quadratic, where you need to find factors of the constant on the end and multiply it with the factors of the first coefficient and plus the other number to get the middle coefficient.

As for your first question: $x^2+10x+21$,

So your factors of 21 are: 1,21,3,7

And your factors of 1 are: 1,1

While $1 \times 21=21, 21+(1 \times 1)=22 \neq 10$

Whereas $1 \times 3=3, 3+(1 \times 7)=10 \checkmark$

So your pair is 3,7

So you start factorising:$(x+3)(x+7)$

To double check it, you can expand it, which in this case:$x^2+7x+3x+21=x^2+10x+21 \checkmark $

For your second question: $x^2+5x-24$,

You can only factorise it by the way which you just did, since none of the Quadratic identities look like the quadratic expression you are going to factorise

Your factors of 24 are: 1,24,2,12,3,8,4,6

And your factors of 1 are: 1,1

Since the sign before 24 is -, you need to subtract your to numbers after they get multiplied.

Let's see our first factor:

$24 \times 1=24, 24-(1 \times 1) \neq 5$

Your second factor:

$1 \times 12=12, 12-(1 \times 2) \neq 5$

Your third factor:

$1 \times 8=8, 8-(1 \times 3) = 5$

So your factor is 3,8

Start factorising:

$(x-3)(x-8)=x^2-12x-2x+24 \neq x^2+5x-24$

The mistake was the sign next to 3,

Correction: $(x+3)(x-8)=x^2-8x+3x-24=x^2+5x-24$

As for your third question:$x^2-x-20$

You just need the factors of 20 to subtract to 1, since it's multiplied by one

Your factors of 20 are: 1,20,2,10,4,5

And $5-4=1$

So your factors are 4,5

Start factorising:

$(x-4)(x-5)=x^2-5x-4x+20 \neq x^2-x-20$

The mistake was made on the sign next to 4,

Correction:

$(x+4)(x-5)=x^2-5x+4x-20=x^2-x-20$